# Install Exaile player 4.0 from source

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

Exaile music player version 4.0 brings a lot of [changes](https://github.com/exaile/exaile/wiki/Exaile-4.0-release-notes), but there is no deb or PPA available.

I have downloaded it from [here](http://www.exaile.org/download/), unpacked it and installed it following the instructions from `INSTALL` file, namely just doing:

```
$ make
# make install
```

which gives no errors.

But there is no Exaile desktop launcher in the usual location (`usr/share/applications`). Instead, it is in `usr/local/share/applications`, which has the line `Exec=exaile --quiet %F`.

But the executable is not present in `usr/bin`, it is instead in `usr/local/bin`.

I have got the normal installation locations by doing the following (after uninstalling with `make uninstall`): I have edited the `Makefile` script and replaced line

```
PREFIX         = /usr/local
```

with

```
PREFIX         = /usr
```

But this doesn't fix it. Now (in Budgie Remix), I have Exaile in the menu launcher (desktop file in `usr/share/applications` and executable in `usr/bin`) but it doesn't start it.

In terminal:

```
~$ exaile
ERROR   : Unhandled exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/exaile/xl/main.py", line 329, in __init__
    self.mainloop_init()
  File "/usr/lib/exaile/xl/main.py", line 595, in mainloop_init
    import dbus
ImportError: No module named dbus
```

[Here](http://exaile.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/install.html#linux-nix) it says the following:

> PREFIX The installation prefix. Default: /usr/local Note: If this
> default is changed, you may need to set the XDG_DATA_DIRS
>
> environment variable to include the changed path. See http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html.

But that surpasses my competence.

---

Could this be fixed to work in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Is your system missing the `python-dbus` package? I don't think the installation directory / `PREFIX` variable is the issue here - `/usr/local/share/applications` is a standard location for .desktop files and personally I wouldn't change `PREFIX` so that `/usr` is reserved for packages that are installed from repos.

Comment: @steeldriver - `python-dbus 1.2.0-3` is installed.

Comment: @steeldriver - you were right, although the package was present. see my answer on how this was fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by @steeldriver in a comment, this may have been a problem with `python-dbus` package. But that was already installed (`python-dbus 1.2.0-3`.)

When in relation to [a separate question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1018550/47206) I have seen that the same package was listed **as not needed anymore** and good to be removed, and after removing it with a lot more others with `sudo apt autoremove`, I decided to try again by installing it manually.

After `sudo apt install python-dbus`, the very same `python-dbus 1.2.0-3` appeared installed, but then Exaile was installed and run successfully with just

```
make
sudo make install
```

To avoid an issue with the [seek bar being absent](https://github.com/exaile/exaile/issues/496):

```
sudo apt install python-gi-cairo
```

---

### Update for 18.04:

**Before** running the `make` and installation commands in the source folder, some packages are needed:

```
sudo apt install python-dbus python-mutagen python-gi-cairo make
```

Comment: Thanks for the addendum, that information was nowhere in the official docs! (At least not in an up-to-date form immediately applicable to Ubuntu 18.04.)