# Can I safely remove all these packages as asked by the message ("Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them")?

Tags: 16.04, apt, 64-bit, uninstall, budgie

I know what that message means after `sudo apt update`, and that it is usually useful and harmless.

But at some point in the past with a different system installation it proposed a lot of programs to remove, and after I did remove them I was left with no **operating** system.

Is it the case here?

Are the following packages vital ones or I can safely remove them?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gcc-5-base:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-x
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
  libasyncns0:i386 libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libbinio1v5
  libbsd0:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386
  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386
  libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386
  libfreetype6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386
  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libhogweed4:i386 libice6:i386 libicu55:i386
  libidn11:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386
  libjpeg8:i386 libjson-c2:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386
  libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libllvm5.0:i386
  libmng2:i386 libmysqlclient20:i386 libnettle6:i386 libogg0:i386
  libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386
  libpng12-0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386
  libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386
  libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386
  libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386
  libqtdbus4:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
  libsdl2-2.0-0 libsensors4:i386 libsm6:i386 libsndfile1:i386
  libsndio6.1 libspeexdsp1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386
  libstdc++6:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtiff5:i386
  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386
  libvorbisenc2:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386
  libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386
  libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386
  libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxml2:i386
  libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386
  libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 python-dbus python-gst0.10
  qt-at-spi:i386 wmctrl
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

I am in Ubuntu Budgie 16.04, 64bit.

---

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

- `sudo apt update` does not provide that list if run by itself; running it after adding a ppa has provided the list
- `sudo apt upgrade` has provided the list
- removing all third party ppa-s, the list still appears (only not after `sudo apt update` solely)

Comment: What was the previous command that led to the autoremove suggestion?

Comment: @DKBose - it was `sudo apt update` after I have added a ppa - but the message and this long list  have appeared before - every time after `apt update`.  I will disable all ppa-s and report again

Comment: Some ppas do pull in newer versions of libraries. So could you check whether you have newer versions of at least some of the packages proposed to be removed?

Comment: Do you have 64 bit installation or 32 bit installation? `cat /etc/*-release` or `uname -a` what does they show?

Comment: All those packages are 32 bit edition if u are on 64bit system they are all useless

Comment: @DKBose In fact even without all my ppas the message is still there

Comment: @dedunumax - as stated clearly in my answer: 64-bit

Comment: :i386 in every package that means they are 32bit version of those packages.

Comment: Anyway leave those packages if you don't have a disk space issue

Comment: @dedunumax - added a new update to the answer; not all packages seem 32-bit, for example:  `python-dbus python-gst0.10 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-x wmctrl`
 - but most are; I know I can leave the packages and I don't have space limitations, but I would like to know how those came about; I didn't even installed wine or playonlinux

Comment: @DKBose -  added a new update to the answer

Comment: Are you on a 64 bit system ? Did you install and remove wine ?

Comment: @Panther - as you may see above: yes 64bit - no, the system was new, no time yet for Wine; that was odd. But is fixed now, I just did it, see my answer. Also incidentally fixed another problem linked there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in a comment by @dedunumax, most packages were 32-bit.

The rest were not vital.

Removing them with `sudo apt autoremove` was a safe procedure.

(But I will reinstall some of those removed - like `python-dbus`, which seems useful for the purpose discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1018205/47206).)